# How to get rid of the xmlns when using xml serialization

Tags: c#, .net

I don't want the following to be appended to the root element

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

what should I do when using XML serialization.

Comment: Yeah, me to, waiting for answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the [Serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163162.aspx) method:

```
public class Foo { }

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(foo.GetType());
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
        serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, foo, ns);
    }
}
```

Notice the last argument (`ns`).

Comment: can you please answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034690/how-to-exclude-property-name-in-xml-serialization-in-web-api-response