# How to exclude property name in Xml serialization in web api response

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

I have a class named GetUnitResponse whose definition is as follows

```
public partial class GetUnitResponse
{
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Name = "GetUnitResponse", Namespace = "", Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Unit", IsNullable=false)]


    public UnitOut[]GetUnitResponse1;

    public GetUnitResponse()
    {
    }

    public GetUnitResponse(UnitOut[] GetUnitResponse1)
    {
        this.GetUnitResponse1 = GetUnitResponse1;
    }
}
```

I'm getting a following xml from the response(GetUnitResponse) object

```
<pre>
<GetUnitResponse xmlns:xsi="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <GetUnitResponse1>
        <Unit day="2016-01-27" ID="572">

        </Unit>
        <Unit day="2016-01-27" ID="573">

        </Unit>
        <Unit day="2016-01-27" ID="574">

        </Unit>
        </GetUnitResponse1>
</GetUnitResponse>
</pre>
```

Client wants the GetUnitResponse1 tag to be excluded and the resultant xml should be like below:

```
<pre>
<GetUnitResponse xmlns:xsi="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">    
        <Unit day="2016-01-27" ID="572">

        </Unit>
        <Unit day="2016-01-27" ID="573">

        </Unit>
        <Unit day="2016-01-27" ID="574">

        </Unit>     
</GetUnitResponse>
</pre>
```

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, ASP.NET Web API uses the [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) to serialize XML. Unfortunately this serializer does not support serializing out a collection as an unwrapped list of elements. On the other hand the [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) allows for more flexible XML and more customizations.

You could instruct ASP.NET Web API to use XmlSerializer instead of the default one:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

And now all that's left is to decorate your field with the `[XmlElement]` attribute:

```
public partial class GetUnitResponse
{
    [XmlElement("Unit")]
    public UnitOut[] GetUnitResponse1;

    ...
}
```

Also for better encapsulation I would recommend you using a property instead of a field.